# Latex page numer 24 goes blank

Tags: latex

I have some problems with numbering pages. Why page number 24 goes blank?
I just don't understand. If I set it on page number 25 it works fine but not with 24.

I've tried messing with fancyhdr but it just don't work

Sorry for my English. Is not my native language.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{\fancyplain{\thepage}{\thepage}}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\setcounter{page}{24}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{\begin{center}
{\small Rozdział 2}
\end{center}}
\title*{\begin{center}
{\huge \textbf{OPRACOWANIE I PREZENTACJA MATERIAŁU STATYSTYCZNEGO}}
\end{center}}
\section*{\begin{center}
2.1. Grupowanie materiału statystycznego
\end{center}}
Materiał liczbowy, otrzymany w wyniku przeprowadzonej obserwacji statystycznej (lub pomiaru), należy odpowiednio usystematyzować i pogrupować w postaci tzw. szeregów statystycznych.

Rozróżnia się zwykle dwa rodzaje grupowania:

- \textit{\textbf{typologiczne}} (np. według cech terytorialnych, rzeczowych, czasowych) mające na celu wyodrębnienia grup różnych jakościowo,

- \textbf{\textit{wariancyjne}}, mające na celu uporządkowanie badanej zbiorowości i poznanie jej struktury, które polega na łączeniu w klasy jednostek statystycznych o odpowiednich wartościach cech statystycznych.

\textbf{Szeregiem statystycznym} nazywamy ciąg wielkości statystycznych, uporządkowanych według określonych kryteriów.

Jak wynika ze schematu (rys. 2.1) przedstawiającego szeregi statystyczne, sposób grupowania cech zależy od rodzaju badania (przekrojowe, czasowe), rodzaju cechy statystycznej, sposobu pomiaru oraz liczby obserwacji (szczegółowe, rozdzielcze).

\textbf{Szeregiem szczegółowym} nazywamy uporządkowany ciąg wartości badanej cechy statystycznej.

Taki sposób porządkowania materiału jest stosowany wtedy, gdy przedmiotem badania jest niewielka liczba jednostek.

Zakładamy, że zmienna \textit{X} przyjmuje wartości: $ x_1 $, $ x_2 $, ..., $ x_n $. Wartości cechy porządkujemy niemalejąco:
$$ x_1 \leqslant x_2 \leqslant ... \leqslant x_n $$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] which allows us to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the book class uses the `twoside` option. This means that new chapters are only allowed to start on odd pages. If you try to start a new chapter on page 24, an empty page gets inserted so the chapter starts on the odd page 25 instead of the even page 24.

If you don't want this, you can use the `oneside` option:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
```